# How to prevent empathy from asking keyring password on every start?

Tags: empathy, keyrings

How to prevent empathy from asking keyring password on every start? I think rhytmbox also asks for my keyring password.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are <strike>2</strike> 3 ways:

1. Don't use auto-login (it's not like having to type a password and then waiting 5 seconds for the desktop to load is going to harm your productivity).
2. If you really want to use auto-login, change the password of your keyring(s) to be empty (but remember that that might expose your passwords for IM/mail accounts, WiFi networks, etc. to other people).
3. In case you are loging in with your password but still get that prompt, then most likely you have different passwords for your keyring & login.  Make them the same and the prompt should go away.

You can change the password through System -> Preferences -> Passwords and Keys (or something like that, I don't have an English GUI currently).

Comment: I cannot change one of those passwords because looks like I've lost it. It's like it have changed without me noticing it. lol
Is there a way to change that password without knowing the old one?

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password