# how to make keyring auto connect?

Tags: keyrings, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent empathy from asking keyring password on every start?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9905/how-to-prevent-empathy-from-asking-keyring-password-on-every-start)

[image]

everytime I login ubuntu, this keyring always pop out. how to make it auto connect?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your keyring or revert your account to original password (not working for auto-login)

Comment: how to delete the keyring? please teach me because ain't good at Ubuntu, I'm newbie