# Change password for gnome-keyring 3.2.2 in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, gnome-keyring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover/reset forgotten Gnome Keyring Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password)

How do I change `gnome-keyring` password in Lubuntu 11.04?

`gnome-keyring` did not prompt me to choose a password when I used the application for the first time.

The default password is the same as my login. I would like to change it and make it stronger.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed that thread. Thanks for pointer - I shall have a look.

Comment: if its not what you are looking for drop a comment and update your question. regards

Comment: Solved this by installing `seahorse` frontend.