# can't download files

Tags: password, administrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset a lost Administrative (root) password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password)

I'm trying to put skype and yahoo messenger onto my Acer Eee note book and the system keeps asking me to give administrator rights and then a password which I can't remember. I tried to change the password and when it comes to typing, I can't. I'm the only one that uses it, so I'd like to make it open.How please?

Comment: Could it be that the reason for "when it comes to typing, I can't" is, that the shell displays nothing when you type a password instead of the maybe expected "*****"? If so, that's the way the shell handles password input. The input is still recognized but nothing is displayed for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to give us more information then that. However, admin rights means you need to run the install commands with **sudo** in front of them. The password is most likely your Ubuntu user password (you were asked to create it at the time of system creation). If you have forgotten that, then you might as well create a new user for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't create any user account without entering the password, Try this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password)