# Reset Login Keyring?

Tags: gnome-keyring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover/reset forgotten Gnome Keyring Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password)

After upgrading from the previous LTS (10.04) to the current LTS (12.04) I got a warning that said my user account password does match the keyring password.

When I go into "passwords and keys" I can not reset "Passwords: Login" as I don't know what thinks the current password is. Can I reinitialize the "Passwords: Login"?