# I continue to get this when trying to log into ubuntu one from the ubuntu desktop

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover/reset forgotten Gnome Keyring Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password)

```
 **Enter password to unlock your login keyring**
```

The password that you use to log into your computer is no longer matches your log in keyring.

Comment: Sounds like you changed your login password for your computer, but you didn't change the password for your keyring. Try using your old computer login password to access your keyring, then change the keyring password to the new one so you don't have this problem. You can do this by pushing Super, then typing "Passwords and Keys". I'll move this to an answer, if this is the case.

Comment: `Applications -> Utilities -> Passwords and Keys` then
Right-click on `Passwords -> login`
Select `“Change Password”`

Answer (score 19):

Click `Applications`

Click `Accessories`

Click `Passwords and Encryption Keys`

**-or-**

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Then type in `seahorse`

-then-

Right click `Passwords: login`

Select `Change Password`

-then-

Change the password to blank. This will allow autologin to use your wireless password, start remote desktop, etc.

**Another way is to remove the old keystore.**

```
killall -9 gnome-keyring-daemon
rm -fr ~/.gnome2/keyrings/
```

reboot the computer `sudo init 6`and then on the first prompt to enter a new keyring password, i.e. when starting empathy or NetworkManager,simply press <kbd>**enter**</kbd>, a warning appears asking `Use insecure storage?`, press <kbd>**enter**</kbd> one more time. From now on, you won't be asked about passwords anymore.
And yes, this is insecure; if you are paranoid, don't do it.
<kbd>enter</kbd>
<kbd>enter</kbd>

---

Edit:  On newer versions of Ubuntu (21.04 in my case) the daemon and directory names seem to have changed:

```
killall -9 gnome-keyring-d
cd ~/.local/share/
rm -rf keyrings
```

Comment: but what if i don't remember the original password anymore???

Comment: if you want to reset your password or just forgot your password you  can follow this:
[link](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)

Comment: it is not working.. it displays the message "give root password for maintenance" when i try to drop to root shell prompt. What shall i do now?

Comment: i used sudo su - root in the normal terminal and then followed the commands to mount and change the pwd subsequemtly, and it worked :D

Comment: i changed the pwd, but it still says the same old message>> **Enter password to unlock your login keyring** and the new password that i just set is incorrect according to it

Comment: I don't know what went wrong but you can try this..

    `killall -9 gnome-keyring-daemon`

    `rm -fr ~/.gnome2/keyrings`


and then on the first prompt to enter a new keyring password, i.e. when starting empathy or NetworkManager,simply press <enter>, a warning appears asking 'Use insecure storage?', press <enter> one more time. From now on, you won't be asked about passwords anymore.
And yes, this is insecure; if you are paranoid, don't do it.</enter></enter>

Comment: A note that on later Ubuntu versions (>=14.x), the keyring file is in `~/.local/share/keyrings`

Answer (score 12):

From the Ubuntu help, it works

1. Go to your Home folder by typing 'home' in the dash.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>(or click View ▸ Show Hidden Files.)
3. Double click on the folder `.gnome2` or `.local/share/keyrings` in Ubuntu >= 14
4. Double click on the folder called keyrings.
5. Delete any files you find in the keyrings folder.
6. Restart the computer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work on my Ubuntu 16.04 distro. Every single step works fine till I get in my .gnome2 folder where I see no keyrings folder. The only folder found there is named "accels" and contains a file names "aisleriot".  So, I'm stuck.

Comment: check .local folder

Comment: This can be a valid answer for problems such as https://askubuntu.com/q/936059/446253. I have fixed a problem on a system driven by Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Works perfectly