# Seahorse does not provide passwords anymore

Tags: skype, seahorse, enigmail, nextcloud

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I am using Skype, Thunderbird with Enigmail and Nextcloud. This three applications have passwords stored by Seahorse and when you enter them once, you don't have to reenter them.

But I don't know why, one morning these three applications were asking me again passwords. And they do each time that I restart now.

Do you have an idea why? It is boring to reenter passwords at each restart, do you know a way to debug this? I'll be glad to provide more information, but right now, I don't know which ones.

**EDIT:**

Details about the packages:

- nextcloud-client from this ppa: ppa:nextcloud-devs/client
- Skype for Linux Beta 5.2.0.1
- Enigmail version 1.9.7 integrated to Thunderird 52.2.1 (Using gpg executable /usr/bin/gpg2 to encrypt and decrypt)

The current version of Seahorse is 3.18.0. When I open it there is no password section, that's maybe a hint. I don't know.

**EDIT 2:**

pgrep -afu "$USER" 'keyring|agent'

```
1602 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
5235 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
5379 gpg-agent --homedir /home/paul/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon
5621 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
```

printenv | grep -e KEYRING -e AGENT

```
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/paul/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Edited

Comment: Thanks. To confirm: (1) Thunderbird only asks for passwords for encryption via Enigmail via GPG (so actually GPG asks for passwords here). (2) Skype for Linux v5 indeed uses Seahorse directly as confirmed on my system. Could you please try to unlock the key chain in `seahorse` manually (right-click the key chain in the panel on the left side and select "unlock") and see if that changes anything?

Comment: (1) I confirm that it only ask the passowrd to encrypt/decrypt emails via Engimail.

(2) Skype for Linux use seahorse

(3) I have unlocked seahorse and checked the box "Unlock automatically when I am logged in" but it didn't change anything (even after restarting)

Comment: About (3): Is the main password key chain currently unlocked? If not, could you please try to unlock it manually?

Comment: (3) I think that I have just discovered an unexpected behaviour right now, I can unlock the keychain by clicking on it but when I click again to lock it, it prints "Couldn't lock, No user has logged in"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62347/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-onda47).

Comment: You might find this useful: https://help.gnome.org/users/seahorse/stable/passwords-view.html.en

Comment: I have found the solution, the question is related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825 the fix is to execute `sudo apt autoremove --purge dbus-user-session`. dbus-user-session is installed with flatpak. Can you post the answer? It seems that I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @onda47 I believe that you can answer a question (even your own!) without having reputation...

Comment: You're right, I couldn't because the post was waiting for more precision.

Comment: Problem encountered also with Ubuntu **14.04** LTS, after installation of Skype for Linux Beta **5.4.0.1** via the Ubuntu Software Centre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, the question is related to this bug: [bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825).

The fix is to execute `sudo apt autoremove --purge dbus-user-session`.

`dbus-user-session` is installed automatically with flatpak.

Comment: Problem encountered also with Ubuntu **14.04** LTS, after installation of Skype for Linux Beta **5.4.0.1** via the Ubuntu Software Centre. In my case the package dbus-user session is not installed as from `dpkg -L dbus-user-session`. So this sort of trouble can have other causes. Interestingly, this issue occurred in one computer of two under expectedly equal conditions and operations.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue showed up after installing Skype for Linux Beta 5.4.0.1 on a system run by Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I had installed Skype via the Ubuntu Software Centre. And there is no package `dbus-user session` installed (check `dpkg -L dbus-user-session`).

This answer https://askubuntu.com/a/191249/446253 fixed the problem. A more elaborate, and perhaps prudent, answer is in https://askubuntu.com/a/65294/446253 (at variance with it I found the keyring to delete in `~/.gnome2/keyrings` while using Ubuntu 14.04).