# Login keyring password "no longer matches"

Tags: password

I just started using Ubuntu on a Parallel desktop off Mac OSx. I am hoping to use this platform to operate my astronomy hardware from my Mac instead of Windows.

The first issue I am encountering is that I am being told my Login Keyring Password "no longer matches" my login. I am confused - I provided a password as I was setting this up, and so I don't know what this is about and how I can fix it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you unlock the keyring with the gui front-end for `seahorse`? To just start over follow the answer [How to recover/reset forgotten Gnome Keyring Password?](https://askubuntu.com/a/65294/723193)

Comment: Usually you get this error if you change your password by some other means which fails to update the password for the keyring. You would need to unlock it using the old password, and change the password to match your login password, to have it unlocked automatically when you log in to the system.

Comment: Thanks. I winded up resetting the computer and redoing everything.

Answer (score 15):

One solution is to run this command to reset your keyring password:

```
rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem for me.

Comment: That works for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a really frustrating problem. Using the password "parallels" works to unlock it on Ubuntu 18.4 - I was having problems installing through pip.

See here for other cases: https://forum.parallels.com/threads/centos-fedora-mint-linux-login-keyring-issue-the-password-you-use-to-login-to-your-computer.343215/

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not remember the old password, a solution for me was to remove the `login.keyring` file under `~/.local/share/keyrings/` on versions of Ubuntu >= 14, and in `~/.gnome2/` on previous versions.

See also the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1355195/630837, here: https://askubuntu.com/a/191249/630837, and the comment here: https://blog.roberthallam.org/2010/07/current-password-does-not-match-keyring-fix/#comment-232503 .