# Password to unlock your login keyring (Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: 19.10, keyrings

My Ubuntu prompts me to unlock login keyring when configuring MySQL Workbench password. I never set such password and nothing seems to work. Is there a way to reset this password? If I call "sudo seahorse", there is no keyring Login. Thank you for your time.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for me was to remove the login.keyring file under "~/.local/share/keyrings/" on versions of Ubuntu >= 14, and in "~/.gnome2/" in previous versions.
See also the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/191249/630837 and comment here: https://blog.roberthallam.org/2010/07/current-password-does-not-match-keyring-fix/#comment-232503 .

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and include the info from the link to the comment, in case of link-rot

Answer (score 0):

The keyring is the administrator password. If you are using an administrator account, or a guest account, you can enter the administrator password in order to unlock the keyring. Ubuntu automatically sets keyrings for security purposes, and you must know the admin passcode to unlock them and access possibly sensitive content.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying with it, but it doesn't seem to work. This is a VirtualBox System and my user is administrator.  I can login, do sudo, but unlocking the keyring does not work.

Comment: Okay. I will try some research. It might be a couple of days before I get back to you.