# How to reset/recover keyrings password on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, keyrings, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover/reset forgotten Gnome Keyring Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password)

Recently, I have been refused to sign on to Ubuntu One. I have been blocked with the message:

> Enter password to unlock your login keyring.

But I have already changed password several times and still getting the same message. I have seen a thread referring to 11.04.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem on 12.04?