# Where are the keyrings folder located in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, keyrings

I want to delete the keychain completely (which has only this one password key anyway).

I found a way to reset keychain / keyring in the forums: delete the keychains folder !

I DO have "show hidden files" activated but my ".gnome2" folder only contains 1 folder called "nautilus scripts" which is empty - nothing else in .gnome2.

There is supposed to be the keychains folder in gnome2 but it is not there.

I searched for keychains keyring seahorse etc but no success.

How can I delete the keychain?

- p.s. the keychains / seahorse window does NOT have any TABs, by the way, it only has the green cross for adding and the search box  ! The keychain should be called "default" but its not there... there are many certificates in the box however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On 12.10 those are located on `~/.local/share/keyrings`

Comment: uuuh thank you for helping a blind man across the street !

Comment: No worries, you helped me fix my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password/65294#65294 I hadnt even had noticed if it was not for this :)