# Why is the login section of "passwords and keys" empty

Tags: 12.10, password, keyrings

Where are passwords stored for the user. As a test I deleted the files stored in `/home/user/.gnome2/keyrings` expecting to have to re-enter my WiFi password at least but it had no effect. So where are passwords stored in 12.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyring files are no longer stored in the `~/.gnome2/keyrings` folder. They are now stored under `$XDG_DATA_HOME` in a combination of the `keyrings` and `keystore` directories.

However, WiFi network passphrases are a special case. As NetworkManager now has support for global vs. per-user network settings, your WiFi passphrase is likely stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` in a file named the same as the WiFi network.

If the only password you've entered into the system is the WiFi passphrase, when you were logged in, and don't have any SSH passphrases or other passwords stored in the keyring, then the keyring will most likely be empty. Deleting the files won't change that.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why I am seeing what I am seeing.  So, I don't have a problem then.  Thanks for answering this for me.

Comment: echo "$XDG_DATA_HOME" returns nothing  for me. Any ideas?

Comment: @coteyr The default for $XDG_DATA_HOME if not specified is $HOME/.config so look in there.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer may help you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password)

This should reset everything:

Short version `rm ~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring`

You will likely need to logout and back in.

If your trying to reset your keys see the link.

Keep in mind that only applications using the keyring will be effected. Network Manager by it's self does not use the keyring. Only the gnome network manager front end does. (Maybe some other network manager front ends do as well).

Comment: Meant to answer the question about where the files are stored

Comment: As I stated in my question I did that and it had no effect on anything.  Now I am wondering where 12.10 stores passwords.  And why is the login section in seahorse empty.  I would expect to see entries there for things like wifi.  In the past they have always been there.

Comment: best answer is it depends.  Most ubuntu apps will use the keyring, but nothing forces them to. Networkmanager's Gnome Front End should be storing your passwords in the keyring. However, it could also store them in /etc/NetworkManage. Kde-wallet, or other places could be used depending on the frontend used, and if they are "system connections" or user specific.