# After Login there is a strange window asking for a password

Tags: login, password

since upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04, I get a window asking  for a password for my email address.  The window appears after logging into the desktop.  The window is titled "Zugangsanfrage" (access request) and "Legitimierungsanfrage" (legitimation request), asks for the password of the acount *my email address*, gives no further information and doesn't let me do anything until I enter a password or cancel the dialog.  It has the option to store the password in the key ring, though.  I can start new apps using the starter bar, but I cannot use them move windows, or type into other windows. I cannot even make a screenshot.

I have not even the slightest idea which password to give.  Does it ask for my web-mail password or for the ubuntu-one password (where my login is the email address) or is it just a phishing app (but how did I get it).  I tried entering some random characters and it is happy.

Update: I added a screenshot: [image: screenshot]

Comment: I've just asked in our chatroom and the quick consensus is this was a keyring window. The keyring stores your various identities and passwords in a secure location. If you've set up a password with truly random keys, you might want to reset the current keyring or you won't be able to unlock it in the future.

Comment: no the window gives no further information.  The full text is:

Comment: Legitimierungsanfrage:  Bitte geben Sie das Password für das Konto "xyz@example.com" ein.  Passwort: ....  [] Fügen Sie das Passwort zum Schlüsselbund hinzu

Comment: it cannot be keyring, as it is asking if I want to store the password in the keyring (this wouldn't make sense, wouldn't it?)

Comment: I do believe that that is the keyring: the checkbox asks if it can store it in the keyring. Now we can not see WHAT it is that asks this so... question: do you have a mail client installed on your system? Or do you use Ubuntu One?

Comment: I have no mail client installed, but I use Ubuntu One.  What is strange is that it does not matter whether I give a password or not.  The Ubuntu One account seems to work (although I did not try to synchronize something). And it is really bad that the dialog does not identify the application that wants a password.

Answer (score 4):

The window comes from gcr-prompter and seems to be this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcr/+bug/1044549

I will try the workaround mentioned there (removing ~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I tried to use evolution, but deinstalled it. Unfortunaltey, some packages left over. Thus, run the following command to check, if all packages from evolution are deinstalled:

```
apt --installed list | grep evolution
```

In my case, the `evolution-data-server` was still installed. Thus, I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get remove evolution-data-server
```

Hint: do not remove the `evolution-data-server-common`. This removes the `indicator-datetime`, which is the clock in the Unity Panel.

Answer (score 1):

It is the gnome-keyring gcr-prompter Window. You can find out using `xprop` (with a delay of 5 seconds to have enough time to bring the window in front)

```
sleep 5 && xprop |egrep 'PID|CLASS'
```

You will see something like

```
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 14458
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gcr-prompter", "Gcr-prompter"
```

So if you never used the keyring or forgot the password, you can simply delete your keyring folder (with backup):

```
mv ~/.local/share/keyrings/ ~/.local/share/keyrings.backup
mkdir ~/.local/share/keyrings/
```

Then Ubuntu will ask to set a new password the next time the Keyring will be used.

see also: [How to recover/reset forgotten Gnome Keyring Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password/65294#65294)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this window was appearing for me because I had previously tried (unsuccessfully) to set up an Exchange email account in Evolution.

As I don't use Evolution, this window served no purpose for me.  I stopped it from re-appearing on every login by wiping my Evolution settings:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/evolution
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a Thunderbird window to me.

To ensure what application is causing that run `xprop`, click on that window and look for the property `_NET_WM_PID` that will give you the PID of the culprit process. Search for that process on `ps aux` or the gnome system monitor to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I have been under KDE with Plasma 5 and was getting this window. I had a home folder with a very long upgrade path (since Ubuntu 10.04). There was an old Folder

```
~/.gnome2/keyrings
```

**Renaming that one** helped me with fixing the unnecessary prompt (I am using KDE's KWallet).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used Gnome online accounts with Google. After removing it, there is no more password request at start.