# Enter Password To Unlock Login Keyring

Tags: 13.04, login, password, keyrings

I had forgotten my password for my user account so I pressed Ctrl + Alt + F2 and loged in as root and ran the following commands

```
root
Password:
passwd harley
Enter NEW Unix Password:
Reeter UNIX Password:
```

then rebooted and logged in then I got a pop-up saying:

> The Password You Used To Log In With Does Not Mach The Password On Your Login Keyring.

What is it asking for: my root password, my old password (That I Forgot), or does it want my current password?

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yep, it asks for your old password. Keyrings do not change them easily.

Comment: Wait a minute! How exactly did you log in as root? BTW, the password for the keyring is totally different than the one for the user, and why you using a joke site?

Comment: It can be reset see [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/65281/107450)