# Problems with Keyring login

Tags: gnome-keyring

I have not been able to log in to keyring..I do not remember EVER having a Key Ring account..so how do I establish a password?

Comment: Please provide a bit more information (Ubuntu version, when it asks for keyring password etc...)

Answer (score 3):

The first time the keyring manager runs it will ask you to enter a keyring password.
This password is used to unlock your keyring / access the stored passwords in your key ring.

To reset your password see this post https://askubuntu.com/a/65294/223798

Comment: It might be a good idea to mention that the keyring password is USUALLY the password that's set on your user account, whether you use the password to login or not.

Comment: @ThomasW. - or to mention that you sometimes have to update the password if you have changed your user password - https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.5/user-changepassword.html.en#changepass - **user238017**, Did you try entering your login password, or any previous ones?