# Change keyring password after resetting password with "passwd" : Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: login, password, keyrings

I forgot my Ubuntu 13.10, so I reset my password from revoverymode using "passwd".
Now when I log in to my system the keyring prompts "The password you use to login to your computer no longer matches that of your login keyring". I googled to change the keyring password but it requires my old password that I don't remember.

Any suggestions on how to solve this.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try live booting with a USB. Then check out this link, it is for 12.10 so I am not sure if it is the same:

[How to recover/reset forgotten Gnome Keyring Password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password)

Another link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/user-forgottenpassword.html

Or if that doesn't work:

I would try getting a live boot of Kali/BackTrack, and use the password cracking tools on there,(or install the tools from another live distro) if no other recovery option works.

Comment: rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring

Comment: Comment above should be the accepted answer.