# Forgot password

Tags: password, reset

I have a dell mini that would not boot to Ubuntu. It sat in my closet for over a year and a half. My son wanted a laptop, so I decided to try and fix it. With the help of this website and adding rootedelay=130 it finally booted but now it's asking for the key ring password which I can't remember cause it's been so long since I've used it. I'd very much appreciate any help in resetting the password. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: @Geo [That's](http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/22949) about the system password. This is asking about the *keyring* password. **Ryan Gotay:** Assuming you don't need to access any data that has been encrypted with the current keyring password, you can just reset it: [How to recover/reset forgotten Gnome Keyring Password?](http://askubuntu.com/q/65281/22949)

Answer (score 0):

You could, in the worst case scenario, do a fresh install. But that shouldn't be so bad of a deal since technically your son will get a brand new OS.