# Forgot default keyring password Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: password, default

So...I forgot it. I actually might have spelled it wrong first...

Any advice?

Comment: Can you log in normally? When does this message show up, and what exactly is the message?

Comment: I can log in normally, yeah. It shows up when I open the browser tab.

Comment: Ok, sounds like the gnome keyring, not the user password that passwd can change. I'm not too sure what to do... found some info, I'll add an A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to delete your current gnome keyring:

```
 rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
```

That should work, but I'm not entirely sure what all will be effected though. You could try & save the old keyring with instructions [from here](https://askubuntu.com/a/65294/129271) though I'm not following step 2 "create a new keyring", might mean to use `seahorse` - other users suggest that `seahorse` alone can fix the problem too.

Answer (score -2):

Well, hopefully you made backups. You could attempt to get in with 3rd party decryption programs, like OphCrack.
Or, you can boot into recovery mode by holding SHIFT while starting.

Find root, then remount ubuntu as un-readonly with this command:

```
 mount -o rw,remount /
```

to access password reset goodness, type:

```
passwd username
```

where *username* is your username.

type `exit` to exit.

credit goes to psychocats, a Ubuntu website I enjoy. http://psychocats.net

Comment: ps. isn't Ophcrack just for windows passwords?

Comment: I was using it as an example, I think there is a linux version. I realize that, however, but the method shown above from psychocats should work.

Comment: This question is about keyrings (used to store website logins etc) not Linux credentials. Your answer is a partial answer to a different question, how to change a Linux login password.