# How do I reset my keyring password for my default keyring?

Tags: keyrings

It wants a password for default keyring, but I don't know it. Is there any way to reset it?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password). Could you please provide more information about the version of Ubuntu (edit your question adding the output of `lsb_release -a`) and more information about you are trying to accomplish?