# Many Authentication requests on startup, NOT remote

Tags: login, password, authentication, 20.10, keyrings

I am on Ubuntu 20.10, quite a "fresh" install.

Very recently, every time I start the computer, I have to enter my password around 6 times, generally 1 Keyring thing, and many "Authentication required for..." "Create color profile", "Refresh repository", "something else about managed color"... and some of them will pop up multiple times. These pop-ups take full focus, like UAC in Windows, so I can't just ignore them either.

On researching this issue, almost every thread is related to remote logging in, XRDP, etc. However, I am not doing that, I am logging it directly at the physical desktop. They also reference a `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/` folder, which I don't have. Instead, I have `localauthority` and `localauthority.conf.d` folders.

The closest thing I can think of related to remote logging in on my system is that I have set up Chrome Remote Desktop although I haven't actually used it yet.

Is there any solution that is not specific to remote logins?

Comment: have you seen: https://askubuntu.com/questions/65281/how-to-recover-reset-forgotten-gnome-keyring-password ... if you changed your password after logging in for the first time, sometimes the keyring gets upset, and seems to ask continually

Comment: I can tell you Chrome Remote Desktop does not do that to me. Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @jad Thanks, I can confirm I have not changed my password/keyring since installing this system about 4 days ago.

Comment: @David Also thank you for that, it's good information that helps us not focus on the wrong things.

Comment: So, on Ubuntu 21.04, I just had this problem and I solved it (so far) by removing the `chrome-remote-desktop` package.  It started this week and installing this package was the only thing I did to my system.  I didn't touch the NVidia drivers, etc.  Maybe it is a combination of the two?  I'm not sure, but since I couldn't get remote desktop working anyway, removing it was easier...

Comment: @Ray yeah it was a HUGE pain getting chrome remote desktop to work, and the performance is really not great, probably going to switch out. I think the convoluted workarounds might have borked some other system settings/driver files, i.e. nvda's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally found a solution that worked for me. Not 100% sure if it's the true fix.

I removed all nvidia-related drivers/packages
`sudo apt purge nvidia*`
`sudo apt purge cuda*`
`sudo apt purge libnvidia*`

Restarted my computer, opened Ubuntu "Software & Updates" - it has defaulted to the open source driver, which causes big screen tearing for me.

Trying to switch it back to 460 (current latest as of writing) (not the server version) didn't work, threw a lot of errors/dependencies at me, but 450 worked (second latest as of writing).

And restarted... dozens of keyring requests are gone, now just 1 (back to how it was originally).

Maybe not a true solution, since I am compromising by rolling back to an older driver version, hopefully this still works when the 460 drivers are fixed on 20.10.